# Reference JSON object with forEach in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In the view, I want to loop through `list` and render `resolved_title` of all list items. This is the JSON object.

```
{ status: 1,
  complete: 1,
  list: 
   { '56777886': 
      { item_id: '56777886',
        resolved_id: '56777897',
        given_url: 'https://youtu.be/5XD2kNopsUs',
        given_title: '',
        favorite: '0',
        status: '0',
        time_added: '1444084808',
        time_updated: '1444392563',
        time_read: '0',
        time_favorited: '0',
        sort_id: 2,
        resolved_title: 'Jason Fried: Why work doesn\'t happen at work',
        resolved_url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XD2kNopsUs&feature=youtu.be',
        excerpt: 'http://www.ted.com Jason Fried has a radical theory of working: that the office isn\'t a good place to do it. At TEDxMidwest he lays out the main problems (call them the M&Ms) and offers three suggestions to make work work.TEDTalks is a daily video podcast of the best talks and performances from the',
        is_article: '0',
        is_index: '0',
        has_video: '2',
        has_image: '1',
        word_count: '0' },
     '240393304': 
      { item_id: '240393304',
        resolved_id: '234209466',
        given_url: 'https://youtu.be/WAuDCOl9qrk',
        given_title: '',
        favorite: '0',
        status: '0',
        time_added: '1444084841',
        time_updated: '1444392557',
        time_read: '0',
        time_favorited: '0',
        sort_id: 1,
        resolved_title: 'John Maeda: How art, technology and design inform creative leaders',
        resolved_url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAuDCOl9qrk&feature=youtu.be',
        excerpt: 'John Maeda, President of the Rhode Island School of Design, delivers a funny and charming talk that spans a lifetime of work in art, design and technology, concluding with a picture of creative leadership in the future. Watch for demos of Maeda\'s earliest work -- and even a computer made of people.T',
        is_article: '0',
        is_index: '0',
        has_video: '2',
        has_image: '1',
        word_count: '0' },
     '714669196': 
      { item_id: '714669196',
        resolved_id: '714669201',
        given_url: 'https://youtu.be/U8-Q70gV2Yk',
        given_title: '',
        favorite: '0',
        status: '0',
        time_added: '1444084869',
        time_updated: '1444575340',
        time_read: '0',
        time_favorited: '0',
        sort_id: 0,
        resolved_title: 'From Storytelling to Storylistening: John Maeda (Future of StoryTelling 2014)',
        resolved_url: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8-Q70gV2Yk&feature=youtu.be',
        excerpt: 'http://futureofstorytelling.orgSee the rest of our 2014 FoST films here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list...Esteemed designer John Maeda discusses how successful leaders apply design thinking and start with storylistening before they get to storytelling.A Future of StoryTelling Film.Find us on',
        is_article: '0',
        is_index: '0',
        has_video: '2',
        has_image: '1',
        word_count: '0' } },
  error: null,
  search_meta: { search_type: 'normal' },
  since: 1444662727 }
```

And below is the view, but I'm getting `body.list.forEach is not a function` error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<% body.list.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <p><%= item.resolved_title %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is not `Array` is `Object` and in `Object` there is not method `forEach`, try this

```
<% Object.keys(body.list).forEach(function(key) { %>
    <p><%= body.list[key].resolved_title %></p>
<% }) %>
```

But better format data in your controller and then pass it to view, like so

```
var titles = Object.keys(body.list).map(function(key)
  return body.list[key].resolved_title;
});

// pass titles to view 

<% titles.forEach(function(title) { %>
    <p><%= title %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I didn't know about this. Please give me a few minutes to accept your answer.